# removing characters from a text in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to manipulate a text in excel using vba. The text I am tyring to manipuate look like the following two texts:

text#1:  ...54

text #2:   ..2

I am trying to remove the dots from these texts so that only the number(s) remains, as follow54

text#1:    54

text#2:     2

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it works:

```
Sub ReplaceDots()

    Dim col as Integer

    col = 2 'The Column where you want to replace the dots

    For Row = 1 To 20 'Define the Range here
        Set curCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, col)
        curCel.Value = Replace(curCel.Value, ".", "")
    Next Row

End Sub
```

edit: maybe i switched rows and columns, you have to test

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Replace` function.

```
Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )
```

*string1* is the string to replace a sequence of characters with another set of characters.

*find* is the string that will be searched for in string1.

*replacement* will replace find in string1.

*start* is optional. This is the position in string1 to begin the search. If this parameter is omitted, the REPLACE function will begin the search at position 1.

*count* is optional. This is the number of occurrences to replace. If this parameter is omitted, the REPLACE function will replace all occurrences of find with replacement.

*compare* is optional. This can be one of the following values:

- vbBinaryCompare   Binary comparison
- vbTextCompare Textual comparison
- vbDatabaseCompare Performs a comparison based on information in your database

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php